# How to add first-launch visual help for a Flutter app?

Tags: flutter

I don't know what is the name of the interactive visual guide that is displayed usually in first launch of mobile application, and how can I add that to my Flutter application?
Thanks

Comment: Those might help

showcaseview: https://medium.com/simform-engineering/flutter-showcaseview-package-35253106ef80 


intro_view: https://pub.dev/packages/intro_views_flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use this package https://github.com/pyozer/introduction_screen

code snippet

```
IntroductionScreen(
  pages: listPagesViewModel,
  onDone: () {
    // When done button is press
  },
  onSkip: () {
    // You can also override onSkip callback
  },
  showSkipButton: true,
  skip: const Icon(Icons.skip_next),
  next: const Icon(Icons.next),
  done: const Text("Done", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600))
);
```

[image]